# Unpacking tiles.lmb inside a .jar file

Tags: java

Planning to revive a 2006 game but i'm stuck and can't unpack the tiles.lmb file to get the png's inside it

jar file:http://dedomil.net/games/2056/screen/8

I'll take any help and thanks

Comment: What did you try?  It seemed to open just fine for me with 7zip.

Comment: @zoredache im trying to open tiles.lmb inside the .jar